# Query for last id in table

Tags: ormlite, query-builder

I need to get the id of the last record in my table.  I have tried:

```
Dao<ParticipantModel,Integer> participantDao  = getHelper().getParticipantsDao();
        participant = participantDao.query(participantDao.queryBuilder()
                 .orderBy("id", false).prepare()).get(1);
```

I'm not sure of how to use the `QueryBuilder` to get the result I'm looking for.  Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 8):

In my application I do the same just add the limit(int) to prepared query like this:

```
Dao<ParticipantModel,Integer> participantDao  = getHelper().getParticipantsDao();
    participant = participantDao.query(participantDao.queryBuilder()
         .orderBy("id", false).limit(1L).prepare());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is more efficient to ask DBMS for maxId in request. Cause DBMS shouldn't perform sorting of rows.
There is a good example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22054283/3086074)

```
    QueryBuilder<MODEL, ID> qb = dao.queryBuilder().selectRaw("max(id)");
    String[] columns = new String[0];
    try {
        GenericRawResults<String[]> results = dao.queryRaw(qb.prepareStatementString());
        columns = results.getFirstResult();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (columns.length == 0) {
        // NOTE: there are not any rows in table
        return 0;
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(columns[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simply:

```
ParticipantModel lastItem = participantDao.queryBuilder().orderBy("id", false).limit(1L).query().get(0);
```