# SQL MAX-MIN in ORMLITE - ANDROID

Tags: android, sql, max, ormlite

I want to know how can i use MAX MIN command with ORMLITE.

For example lets say we have this table

> Table Name = Example
> Column 1 = id
> Column 2 = name

In ORMLITE how can i get max id ? I looked  [here](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#Advanced/) but i didnt't understand exactly..

Can someone show me example about Max min in ORMLITE ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
QueryBuilder<Account, Integer> qb = accountDao.queryBuilder();

qb.selectRaw("MIN(orderCount)", "MAX(orderCount)");

// the results will contain 2 string values for the min and max

results = accountDao.queryRaw(qb.prepareStatementString());

String[] values = results.getFirstResult();
```

I found this from [documentation](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#Raw-Statements)

Answer (score 4):

This is how I query for max ID in my code:

```
QueryBuilder<Example, String> builder = dao.queryBuilder();
builder.orderBy("id", false);  // true or false for ascending so change to true to get min id
Example example = dao.queryForFirst(builder.prepare());
String id = null;
if (example == null)
    id = "-1";
else
    id = example.getId();
```

A couple of alternative answers can also be found here:
[ORMLite - return item w/ maximum ID (or value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970221/ormlite-return-item-w-maximum-id-or-value)

Comment: +1 You should also add a `limit(1)` since there is only going to be one result returned.

Comment: @Gray - just one point: in newer versions of ORMLite limit(int) is deprecated. You have to use limit(1L). But thanks to both of you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

dao.queryRawValue("select MAX(columnName) from tableName")

It will directly return long value.

> refer: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#DAO-Methods
>
> queryRawValue(String query, String... arguments)
>
> Perform a raw query that returns a single value (usually an aggregate function like MAX or COUNT). If the query does not return a single long value then it will throw a SQLException.